# FTPClient check permissions

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons-net

if I have a ftp server at ftp://ftpdomainname.com and I want to upload file to it, how do I check for its permissions using [Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) ?

I try:

```
ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(url.getHost());

ftpClient.login(username, pass);

FTPFile[] directories = mFtpClient.listDirectories("/");
for(FTPFile dir : directories) {
    permissions = dir.hasPermission(FTPFile.USER_ACCESS, FTPFile.READ_PERMISSION);
}
```

but it's not getting the permissions for the root server (folder) but for its subfolders.

Can i specify url like ftp://ftpdomainname.com/ and get whether I have write permissions? Or url like ftp://ftpdomainname.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/ ?

Thanks

Comment: Which FTP client library are you using ? Is it [Commons NET](http://commons.apache.org/net/) one ?

Comment: Is the parent directory ".." one of the FTPFiles returned by the listDirectories method?

Answer (score 1):

Using Commons Net 3.1 [`FTPClient`](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) class, you could try obtaining current FTPFile by issuing the following command

```
 FTPFile current = mFTPClient.listFiles(".")[0];
 // Then check permissions as your upper code does.
```

As, after all, on most hosts, the current file can be accessed through ".".

**EDIT** some clarifications according to comment.

Suppose you just connected to your FTP server (before to try to upload file) :

```
ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(url.getHost());

ftpClient.login(username, pass);
```

Once it is done, immediatly try to get access to current folder (which should be your default user folder, in other words the folder where you want to upload your file) :

```
 FTPFile current = mFTPClient.listFiles(".")[0];
```

In this folder, read permissions, and you'll have permissions for your root folder :

```
current.hasPermission(FTPFile.USER_ACCESS, FTPFile.READ_PERMISSION);
```

Want to write something ? Then check the WRITE_PERMISSION.

Comment: let me make myself more clear. If I want to upload a file to  ftp://ftpdomainname.com - how do I check if I have permissions on the server (that host, which is the root of the server) to store the file there?